# C++ ignores the second input if the type of the first input in not correct

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, cin

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int var1;
    float var2;

    cout << "input var1:";
    cin >> var1;
    cout << "var1 = " << var1 << endl;

    cout << "input var2:";
    cin >> var2;
    cout << "var2 = " << var2 << endl;
}
```

If I assign a float value to the variable var1, then var1 takes on the value of the integer part of the input, while var2 is automatically assigned the value of the decimal part of the input.

Example 1: in this case the programs runs correctly:

```
input var1: 40
var1 = 40
input var2: 3.5
var2 = 3.5
```

Example 2: in this case the program ignores the second input:

```
input var1: 1.5
var1 = 1
var2 = 0.5
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: The  `int` extractor is greedy. After skipping whitespace it will pull any optional sign indicator, then digits until it runs into something not-digit. That is what is happening. `1`, then when `.` is encountered, not digit, so stop. So the `int` is "done" as far as the pull is concerned, and successful. Next you try to read a float, and you still have `.5` in the input stream, left over after the `int` pull. Its a float, so again. success. In short, the second isn't "ignoring" anything. It's pulling exactly what you asked for, in the order you asked, for the data you provided.

Comment: If you want your inputs to be logically separated line-by-line, the canonical way is to use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).